# Invalid ASCII characters found in API key While Creating Account on Stripe?

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, stripe-connect, stripe.net

I am following [Stripe create account](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_account) document and trying to create an account

I am using WebRequest (C#) to do so. but while making a request On Fiddler I am getting an Json Error Response saying.

```
{
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "Invalid ASCII characters found in API key: "----".  For assistance, please contact support@stripe.com.",
    "code": "invalid_ascii_in_key"
  }
}
```

creating Authorization header as following.

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Concat("Basic ", String.Format("{0}", APIKey)))
```

P.S. , I can use `Stripe.net` , If it provides functionality to do so. (from my research it doesn't provide this.)

**`message=Invalid ASCII characters found in API key: "-----------".  For assistance, please contact support@stripe.com.`**

Thanks for the help , In advance..

Comment: It should be Bearer API_KEY not Basic API_KEY

Comment: I first tried that  , but it didnt work , some answers posted at SO for other threads have Basic so I tried that ..unfortunately none of them worked.

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution for this?